# One out of four radio buttons hidden

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have four sets of radio buttons, each set wrapped in a div called "choiceSet". On firefox for windows I see all four sets of radio buttons. My coworker only sees three sets in firefox. Both of us see only 3/4 sets in chrome. In linux I don't see the offending set of radio buttons regardless of the browser.

Any ideas? Whenever I have a problem like this in Python it turns out that I used a reserved word for something.

The html is here: 
https://github.com/melvyniandrag/SentimentLabeler/blob/master/mysite/polls/templates/polls/detail.html

Here is the offending html/django:

```
<div class="choiceSet">
    <h3>Ad?</h3>
    {% for advertisement in question.advertisement_set.all %}
        {% if 'not' in advertisement.ad_text %}
            <input type="radio" name="advertisement" id="advertisement{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ advertisement.id }}" checked/>
        {% endif %}
        {% if 'not' not in advertisement.ad_text %}
            <input type="radio" name="advertisement" id="advertisement{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ advertisement.id }}" />
        {% endif %}
        <label for="advertisement{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ advertisement.ad_text }}</label><br />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

which becomes:

```
<div class="choiceSet"> 
    <h3>Ad?</h3>
    <input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="advertisement" id="advertisement1" value="17" />
    <label for="advertisement1">advertisement</label><br />
    <input type="radio" class="radiobutton" name="advertisement" id="advertisement2" value="18" checked/>
    <label for="advertisement2">not advertisement</label><br />
</div>
```

the css is here: `https://github.com/melvyniandrag/SentimentLabeler/blob/master/mysite/polls/static/polls/detail.css`

If you

```
git clone https://github.com/melvyniandrag/SentimentLabeler.git
cd mysite
python manage.py runserver
open 127.0.0.1:8000
login a/password
```

you will see the problem.

Comment: Please add your code to thevqurstion, not just a link and please tell which of the choice sets is not shown.

Comment: Hi Klaus, I added the problematic html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was pretty interesting :)

I was able to reproduce this. The problem is that the second choiceSet  has radio buttons with id "advertisement*", which triggers the AdBlockPlus Plugin in chrome and automatically hides that div, acting as a false positive!

Here is a small proof:

[image]

[image]

The solution is just to change the value of id to something like "adv-mnt1"

Comment: BRILLIANT thanks so much for the effort! Very 'open minded thinking' on your part!